# How do I write a "not equal to" condition where a number should be interpreted as text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in my Excel-sheet, we can call them A and B. I'm trying to use the =SUMIFS() function in Excel to sum all numbers in column B if the adjacent cell i column A is not equal to 4. This is what I've done:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"<>4")
```

My problem is that column A is formatted as text (and I want to keep it this way) and when I do my "not equal to"-statement the 4 is interpreted as a number and not as text which means that the adjacent cell in column B gets summed even though it's not supposed to. How do I get Excel to interpret my 4 as text?
I've already tried entering extra quotation marks as below but this does not work.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"<>"4"")

and

=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"<>'4'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one would need to use SUMPRODUCT:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(B1:B9*(A1:A9<>"4"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use another cell as criteria, using only quotation marks may not be interpreted correctly. In this example i used cell G4 for criteria.

[image]

Comment: Try entering each value as text `'4` and not formatting the cell as text. This will not work if each value is entered as text, like from an import.  It does work if you format the cells as text, but then again, if the OP had it that way their first formula would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"<>*4") works